# Best Azure region for Middle-East

Tags: azure

What is the best [Azure region](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/) for a website accessed by users in the Middle East (i.e. Gulf, Egypt, Northern-Africa ...), would it be **US** or **Europe** regions?

Comment: sorry Andrew - but this IS a great question and one I see a lot in various incantations. It has a good answer too - see below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a tough one. It depends on exactly where you are, your ISP and its peering. To check this out for you, see my article over on 
http://tfl09.blogspot.dk/2015/02/your-nearest-azure-data-centre.html
which shows you a tool I found to work out access times to Azure regions. Run this from your system in the Middle east and see which center is closest. I suspect West Europe, but could well be wrong.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot for the link, you nailed it :)

Comment: by the way is there any speed tests like this for Amazon or digital ocean?

Comment: I have not seen a calculator like this for AWS or any other cloud supplier. Maybe Andrea Schulman has?